# How to fetch multiple results that reside in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a query that will return a count of the `views` column based on a single user's `id`.

Here is the table's contents:

```
id |  post_id | user_id | views

1 |      4     |   67    | 4
1 |      56     |   67    | 3
1 |      34     |   67    | 10
```

I want to get the total of posts views the user have

```
SELECT *,count(views) from users WHERE user_id = 67
```

The result have to be **17**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, sum(views) FROM users WHERE user_id = 67 GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `SUM` operator.

```
SELECT SUM(views) FROM users WHERE user_id = 67
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) up the views:

Simple approach:

```
SELECT SUM(views) 
FROM users
WHERE user_id = 67;
```

More complex approach:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(views) 
FROM users
WHERE user_id = 67
GROUP BY user_id;
```